# PHP Create JSON Friendly array from SQL Select

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to produce JSON from an SQLSRV query. I believe the best way to do this is retrieve the data and build a valid array which can then be run through json_endode().

I am having problems building the array.

I have the following SQL Statement. It is a classic one to many SELECT.

```
SELECT
    OrderHeader.SiteId,
    OrderHeader.OrderRef,
    OrderDetail.JobRef,
    OrderDetail.Qty,
    OrderDetail.ActionDate,
    OrderDetail.ContractorId
FROM
    OrderHeader
INNER JOIN
    OrderDetail ON OrderHeader.OrderHeaderId = OrderDetail.OrderHeaderId
WHERE
    OrderHeader.OrderRef = '0001008'
```

It SELECTS the following data:

```
SiteId  OrderRef    JobRef      Qty ActionDate  ContractorId
1       0001008     1000001021  1   2010-04-21  1
1       0001008     1000001034  1   2010-05-07  1
1       0001008     1000001035  1   2010-05-12  1
1       0001008     1000001172  1   2010-06-09  1
1       0001008     1000001276  1   2010-06-24  1
```

The PHP that retrieves the rows and produces my current array looks like this:

```
$RS_Result01 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

$result1 = array();
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS_Result01,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS_Result01,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

print_r($result);
```

Which produces the following array output.

```
Array 
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => 1000001034
                [Qty] => 1
                [ActionDate] => 2010-05-07 00:00:00.000
                [ContractorId] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => 1000001035
                [Qty] => 1
                [ActionDate] => 2010-05-12 00:00:00.000
                [ContractorId] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => 1000001172
                [Qty] => 1
                [ActionDate] => 2010-06-09 00:00:00.000
                [ContractorId] => 1
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => 1000001276
                [Qty] => 1
                [ActionDate] => 2010-06-24 00:00:00.000
                [ContractorId] => 1
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => 1000001027
                [Qty] => 1
                [ActionDate] => 2010-04-28 00:00:00.000
                [ContractorId] => 1
            )
    )
```

This is relativly standard output. What I would like to produce is something like this that I can use for a cleaner JSON conversion.

```
Array 
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SiteId] => 1
                [OrderRef] => ORD0001008
                [JobRef] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [JobRef] => 1000001034
                                [Qty] => 1
                                [ActionDate] => 2010-05-07 00:00:00.000
                                [ContractorId] => 1
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [JobRef] => 1000001035
                                [Qty] => 1
                                [ActionDate] => 2010-05-12 00:00:00.000
                                [ContractorId] => 1
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [JobRef] => 1000001172
                                [Qty] => 1
                                [ActionDate] => 2010-06-09 00:00:00.000
                                [ContractorId] => 1
                            )
                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [JobRef] => 1000001276
                                [Qty] => 1
                                [ActionDate] => 2010-06-24 00:00:00.000
                                [ContractorId] => 1
                            )
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [JobRef] => 1000001027
                                [Qty] => 1
                                [ActionDate] => 2010-04-28 00:00:00.000
                                [ContractorId] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I have tried multiple ways of doing this but I have spent hours going round in circles. I could really use some assistance and an explanation to help me understand a solution.

Kind regards

Comment: Will SiteId be always same like OrderRef?

Comment: I think your question does not need query details etc. You could trim it down for readability purposes

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: it's not a very good idea. Editing the SQL query may help to solve the problem. (adding an `ORDER BY OrderHeader.SiteId` for instance)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: also note that SQL server is able to produce JSON itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe a simpler and faster way, but I wrote it this way mostly for readability.

---

Concept:

1. Iterate through results
2. Create a "hash" value with the two pieces of data you are grouping by (`SiteId` & `OrderRef`)
3. Add `JobRef`s as you iterate through the results, adding them to the end result.

---

```
$siteOrderJobRefs = [];

// --- 1
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $siteId = $row['SiteId'];
    $orderRef = $row['OrderRef'];

// --- 2
    $key = md5($siteId . $orderRef);
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $siteOrderJobRefs)) {
        $siteOrderJobRefs[$key] = [
            'SiteId'   => $siteId,
            'OrderRef' => $orderRef
        ];
    }

// --- 3
    $siteOrderJobRefs[$key]['JobRef'][] = [
        'JobRef'       => $row['JobRef'],
        'Qty'          => $row['Qty'],
        'ActionDate'   => $row['ActionDate'],
        'ContractorId' => $row['ContractorId']
    ];
}
```

[Optionally], if you do not want the hashed keys, you could reset to numerical order:

```
$siteOrderJobRefs = array_values($siteOrderJobRefs);
```

In order to return a JSON string of this array:

```
$jsonResult = json_encode($siteOrderJobRefs);
```

---

Other notes: you don't even really need to hash the key, but it would help create distinctiveness of the grouped values.

Comment: This is exactly along the lines I was thinking but my PHP/syntax abilities were letting me down. Thanks for a readable answer to this. Appreciate the explanation.

I am thinking that turning this into a more flexible solution would be possible if I removed the SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC so that I was able to use the numeric array identifier:

    $siteId = $row[0];
    $orderRef = $row[1];

In which case is it possible to hash encode a given range of array values or all values except a given one instead of explicitly adding them to the hash?

Comment: In that case, you could use `array_slice()` in order to get the range of values and then `implode()` joining them together.
Result would be: `$key = implode(array_slice($row, 0, 2));`. 
Refer to: http://php.net/array_slice

Answer (score 0):

A workable, if inelegant solution, would be to use a `foreach` loop to transverse this array and populate a separate, new array that includes a `JobRef` subarray for each entry.  That sub-array would receive entries whenever `SiteId` and `OrderRef` match in the loop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20950004)

Comment: It’s the same content as the accepted answer but without code.  I don’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce an array in that format as you fetch the rows from your query result. Shift off the first two elements of each row to get the SiteID and OrderRef, and then append the remaining columns to the JobRef key.

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS_Result01,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result['SiteId'] = array_shift($row);
    $result['OrderRef'] = array_shift($row);
    $result['JobRef'][] = $row;
}
```

SiteId and OrderRef will be overwritten with each iteration, but that should be fine with that query because it looks like they'll be the same for each row.

There's another array level around the result you want, but you can add that when you encode, like

```
json_encode([$result]);
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, which works pretty well for this test set. I am going to experiment with expanding it to include a loop and a check to conditionally array_shift